# Using value from select statement inside of subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have something like this (pseudocode):

```
select 
case when (condition) then t1.value else (select value from t2) end as MyVal,
case when (condition) then t1.secondValue else (select value from t3 where x = MyVal) end as WhyDoesntThisWork
from t1
```

As you can see, in a second case we have `where x = MyVal`, and it does not allow me to use MyVal. Is there any simple way of using MyVal in subquery?

Comment: Are both the conditions are same in myVal, whydoesntthiswork?  `CASE WHEN (condition)`

Comment: MyVal does not even make sense  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2005 and more recent (`tsql` tag you've used assumes you're using SQL Server DBMS), you can use `outer apply`:

```
select 
    CALC.MyVal,
    case 
       when (condition) then t1.secondValue 
       else (select value from t3 where x = CALC.MyVal) 
    end as WhyDoesntThisWork
from t1
    outer apply (select 
                  case 
                       when (condition) then t1.value 
                       else (select value from t2) 
                  end as MyVal
    ) as CALC
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, you cant because Myval doesnt exist on that context. Will be created after finish process the row.

Depending on your RDBMS you could create an CTE.

Or just repeat the code.

```
select 
    case 
        when (condition) then t1.value 
        else (select value from t2) 
    end as MyVal,
    case 
        when (condition) then t1.secondValue 
        else (select value 
              from t3 
              where x = case 
                           when (condition) then t1.value 
                           else (select value from t2) 
                        end
             ) 
    end as WhyDoesntThisWork
from t1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues in your query:

- You cannot use the column alias `MyVal` to compute another column as it is not within the scope of particular select statement  .
- The next issue is in your case statement you are trying to use values from a subquery without any filter or join ( for e.g. `select value from t2`). This will return all the rows from your table `t2` and therefore, return an error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Subquery returned more than 1
>   value.

Making some assumptions here, you could either use `CTE` or a subquery to use `MyVal` alias in your outer query like this:

```
SELECT t.id
    ,t.MyVal
    ,CASE 
        WHEN (condition)
            THEN t.secondValue
     ELSE t3.value
     END AS ThisWorksNow
FROM (
    SELECT id
         ,CASE 
            WHEN (condition)
                THEN t1.value
          ELSE t2.value
          END AS MyVal
        ,t1.secondvalue
    FROM t1
    INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id_fk
    ) t
INNER JOIN t3 ON t3.X = t.MyVal
```